# Как получить json из get запроса?

Tags: python, json, http, get, https

Кто знает, как можно `http` запрос разобрать и извечь `get` запрос в виде `json` на `python`?

Например имею переменную с ссылкой

```
site.com/test?val=1&tal=2
```

и получить её как

```
{val:1,tal:2}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: dict urllib.parse.parse_qsl или urllib.parse.parse_qs но в качестве значений получите списки. https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse

Answer (score 2):

Для Python формат json буквально означает - словарь. Документацию по преобразованию можно глянуть [здесь](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html). То есть, формализуя вашу задачу, необходимо забрать данные `query` из ссылки и превратить в словарь, а затем этот словарь в строку с `json`-форматом

Приступим

```py
from urllib import parse
import json

url = "site.com/test?val=1&tal=2"
value_like_dict = dict(parse.parse_qsl(parse.urlsplit(url).query))
value_like_json = json.dumps(value_like_dict)

print(f"Это словарь: {value_like_dict}")
print(f"Это json: {value_like_json}")
```

Вывод

```
Это словарь: {'val': '1', 'tal': '2'}
Это json: {"val": "1", "tal": "2"}
```